# How do I open a mini webpage inside a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've tried to open a mini webpage inside a chrome extension which I made, but as you can see it's not working:

[image]

I've tried referencing [www.pinterest.com](http://www.pinterest.com) "which is the website I want to access" but it keeps giving me this message as shown in the image above what should I do to make it work or is it even possible

here is a photohshoped image of what I want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't open random pages within the sidebar/popup; only pages packaged with your extension can be opened here. You can however open the page in the main browser window (for example by adding 'target="_blank"' to links in your side panel or by updating window.location.href (through a service worker).

Answer (score -1):

With the little information you've provided, there's only so much I can do to help you. A great place for information on web extension development is always MDN. Perhaps their [article on how to add a popup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Popups) or their [example extension](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/main/beastify) can help you.

There's also an [example by Opera](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/extension-samples/browser-actions-button.crx) if you want to try theirs. Speaking of Opera, perhaps their [guide on debugging extensions in Opera](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/testing/) helps. Have you double-checked you are pointing to the right file?

It would be really helpful if you could provide a version of the extension with just the necessary code to cause your issue.